# Debian : Terminal appears but GUI does not work

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, embedded

I installed debian in virtualbox, and I'm trying to design an operating system for lichee pi board but when I execute these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Lichee-Pi/linux.git
cd linux
make ARCH=arm licheepi_zero_defconfig
make ARCH=arm menuconfig #add bluethooth, etc.
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -j16
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -j16 INSTALL_MOD_PATH=out modules
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -j16 INSTALL_MOD_PATH=out modules_install
```

I have a bug in the debian OS where I cannot handle the GUI and the desktop is not showing ..
Terminal is the only one that can only handle it, I want gui

[image: Image-1]

[image: Image-2]

Comment: I don't see you trying to start a graphical environment anywhere in your screenshots.

Comment: @Panki When I first installed the operating system, Terminal wasn't showing up, rather the desktop